# Utilizing Pop to return

Tags: arm, keil

This is a re-update to the post. In the comments of the code, the "removed" comment represents the error that has been changed, and a comment with "new" means that it replaced the "removed" line. My initial error was due to my code never returning for the next set of values. As mentioned below by Nate Eldredge, my problem was happening because "POP {ro, lr}" was attempting to jump to the next set of values but there was no value for lr to go to. Re-placing "POP {r0, lr}" with "BX lr" and removing "PUSH" allows the function to proceed to the 1st set and go to the 2nd set of values. Hopefully, if anyone else has any issues with this in the future this information will be useful to them.

I'm trying to carry r0 & r1 over in a loop, and when that loop is finished it will return to its previous position. When x0 & y0 have been calculated then x1 & x2 will be calculated. The code below allows each unit of values to branch to the loop:

```
    ADR    r0, x0                    
    ADR    r1, y0                    
    LDR    r2, e0                    
    BL     euclid                     ; Branch for 1st iteration.
    ADR    r0, x1                    
    ADR    r1, y1                    
    LDR    r2, e1                    
    BL     euclid                     ; Branch for 2nd iteration.
    ADR    r0, x2                    
    ADR    r1, y2                    
    LDR    r2, e2                    
    BL     euclid                     ; Branch for 3rd iteration.
    ;PUSH {r0, r1, LR}                 REMOVED
    B      done
```

The code below is supposed to move back to where it left off:

```
exit        STR    r0, [r2]
            BX     LR                 ; NEW: Allows for return 
            ;POP    {r0, r1, pc}       REMOVED
done        B      done               ; endless loop to stop the program
```

I have tried other methods such as POP{pc} and changing positions, but none of those methods have worked.

Here is the minimal reproducible example:

```
            AREA   Example, CODE, READWRITE  
            ENTRY
       
            ADR    r0, x0                   ; 1st value  
            LDR    r1, e0
            BL     enterloop
            ADR    r0, x1                   ; 2nd value 
            LDR    r1, e1
            BL     enterloop 
            ADR    r0, x2                   ; 3rd value 
            LDR    r1, e2
            BL     enterloop 
            B      DONE
            ;PUSH   {r0, lr}                 REMOVED

enterloop   CMP    r0, #0
            BEQ    exit                       ; when 0 exit loop.
            ADD    r0, r0, #1                 ; adds 1 to x? value.
            B      enterloop

exit        str    r0, [r1]
            BX     LR                      ; NEW: Allows for return
            ;pop    {r0, pc}                   REMOVED
done        b      done                       ; endless loop to stop the program

x0          DCD    -8
x1          DCD    -9
x2          DCD    -13
e0          SPACE   4
e1          SPACE   4
e2          SPACE   4
e3          SPACE   4
            END
```

Comment: Hint: what address is in LR at the moment you push it?

Comment: You should really show us a [mcve] though.  The snippet here doesn't really make sense in isolation.

Comment: I posted an example of the code at the bottom of the post.

Comment: You need to push r0 and LR at the very beginning of your function.  On entry, LR contains the address you should return to, but any subsequent `bl` instruction overwrites LR, so you have to push it before then.  Likewise, presumably the reason for pushing and popping r0 is so that you restore the value it originally had (if it is supposed to be call-saved in your program), so then you need to push it before any instruction that writes to r0.

Comment: But wait a sec.  The `ENTRY` makes it look like this is the entry point to your whole program.  In that case, `pop pc` likely won't work, as there is nowhere in your program to return to - LR didn't contain a useful value on program entry.  So then you would be expected to issue an exit system call (if running under an OS) or branch to your infinite loop.

Comment: I think what we need next is the spec for what you are trying to accomplish.  How will this program be loaded and run?  What will it do with the result of the computation?  What is it supposed to do when it finishes? If it's a homework, as it appears, then show the statement of the assignment.

Comment: Essentially, I am trying to iterate Euclid's algorithm in my assignment. "X" (r0) and "y" (r1) are the values to be input and "e" (r3) is what I am storing the results in. The first set x0 and y0 are being calculated correctly, but when the first set is finished the code halts on "POP". So, the 2nd set of values is never implemented.

Comment: Also, I did try placing "PUSH" below "ENTRY" and you are right the code keeps cycling the same value. Now, if I place "PUSH" below the 1st set, then the code will cycle on "POP" infinitely. Why exactly will it not break the cycle? Would I need another register to go to?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I ended up replacing "POP {LR}" for "BX LR" and that allows the code to start out where it left off.